# Is T a continuous linear map?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

For the function  $f \in L^2 ([-\pi,\pi])$ define the map $ T: L^2([-\pi, \pi]) \to R $ as $T(f)=a_1+b_1 $ if the Fourier series of $f$ is of the form

$f $ ~ $a_0 +\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_ncos(nx)+b_nsin(nx)) $

How to prove that T is a continuous linear map?

I took the limit to infinity to show that $lim T(f-f_n) = T(f)-lim T(f_n)=a_1+b_1-(a_1+b_1)=0$ it is what intuition suggests me, however i do not have a ground for such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since$$a_1=\frac1\pi\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t)\cos(t)\,\mathrm dt=\frac1\pi\langle f,\cos\rangle,$$the map $f\mapsto a_1$ is continuous. A similar argument shows that $f\mapsto b_1$ is continuous too and so your map is the sum of two continuous functions.

Comment: Note that $a_1(f_1+f_2)=\frac1\pi\langle f_1+f_2,\cos\rangle=\frac1\pi\langle f_1,\cos\rangle+\frac1\pi\langle f_2,\cos\rangle=a_1(f_1)+a_1(f_2)$ and that $a_1(\lambda f)=\frac1\pi\langle\lambda f,\cos\rangle=\lambda\frac1\pi\langle f,\cos\rangle=\lambda a_1(f)$.

Comment: Dear Jose, really thanks again! I deleted comment because I understand why it is linear and I am sorry for bothering you with such silly questions.

Comment: If you do not mind, can you look at continuation of this problem? I posted separately, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3472635/how-to-find-function-h-in-l2-pi-pi-so-that-tf-int-pi-pi-fx

Answer (score 3):

By Parseval's Theorem we have that $$\sum_{n \in \Bbb{Z}}|\hat{f}(n)|^2=||f||_2^2$$ or $$\frac{a_0^2}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n^2+b_n^2=||f||_2^2$$

So $|T(f)|^2 \leq 2(|a_1|^2+|b_1|^2) \leq \frac{2a_0^2}{2}+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n^2+b_n^2=2||f||_2^2$

Thus the operator is bounded.

Comment: Dear Marios, Thanks for clarification! If you do not mind I asked the continuation of this problem separately, can you look at it? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3472635/how-to-find-function-h-in-l2-pi-pi-so-that-tf-int-pi-pi-fx