# How to find function $h \in L^2 ([-\pi,\pi])$ so that $T(f)=\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)h(x)dx $

Tags: real-analysis, operator-theory, fourier-series

For the function  $f \in L^2 ([-\pi,\pi])$ define the map $ T: L^2([-\pi, \pi]) \to R $ as $T(f)=a_1+b_1 $ if the Fourier series of $f$ is of the form

$f $ ~ $a_0 +\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_ncos(nx)+b_nsin(nx)) $ find function $h \in L^2 ([-\pi,\pi])$ so that $T(f)=\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)h(x)dx $

In order to find $h$ I started the following $ \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)h(x)dx=a_1+b_1$ then

$f(x)$~$a_0+a_1 cosx+b_1sinx + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(a_n cos(nx)+b_nsin(nx))h(x)dx$

$\int_{-\pi}^\pi a_0h(x)dx=0 $

$ \int_{-\pi}^\pi(\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(a_ncosnx+b_nsinnx)h(x)dx=0 $

then $ \int_{-\pi}^\pi (a_1cosx+b_1sinx)h(x)dx=a_1+b_1 $

and then i got following: $ \int_{-\pi}^\pi a_1cosxh(x)dx=1$ which will be $\int_{-\pi}^\pi cosxh(x)dx=1$

and same logic for be I got integral sinxh(x) is equal to 1. However, I do not know how to proceed forward is in order to find h(x). Can you please help me out? I could not find intuitive way of solving this problem.

Comment: I dont see the mystery here as far as you knows how to calculate the Fourier coefficients of a function, that is, the solution is immediate from the definition of $a_1$ and $b_1$

Comment: Dear Masacroso, can you please elaborate if you do not mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fourier coefficients are defined by
$$a_0:=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\,\mathrm d x\\ a_n:=\frac1{\pi }\int_{-\pi }^\pi f(x)\cos(nx)\,\mathrm d x\\
b_n:=\frac1{\pi }\int_{-\pi }^\pi f(x)\sin(nx)\,\mathrm d x
$$
for $n\in \Bbb N_{> 0} $. Therefore $h(x)=\frac1{\pi }(\cos (x)+\sin(x))$.